# Cursor coordinates when zooming canvas js

Tags: javascript, canvas, coordinates, zooming

Good afternoon!
When writing the function of scaling inside the canvas there was a problem with the calculation of coordinates. If the cursor is in the center of the canvas, scaling occurs evenly in all directions, but if the cursor is in any other point, the image is scaled incorrectly and goes to the side. What is the correct way to redefine the coordinates so that at any position of the cursor the image is scaled evenly in all directions?

```
function scale() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const canvas_width = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
        const canvas_height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

        canvas.addEventListener("wheel", onmousewheel, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", onmousewheel, false);
    
        var position = {x: 0, y: 0};
    
        function onmousewheel(event) {
            var x = event.clientX - position.x + canvas_width/2;
            var y = event.clientY - position.y + canvas_height/2;
            const delta = event.type === "wheel" ? event.wheelDelta : -event.detail;
            const increment = delta > 0 ? 1.1 : 0.9;
    
            const previous_scale = scale;
            scale *= increment;
    
            position.x -= x * (scale / previous_scale - 1);
            position.y -= y * (scale / previous_scale - 1);

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, 0, scale, position.x, position.y);
            CANVAS.draw(); // separate function for drawing all elements on the canvas
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Also interested, how can I make the animation of the canvas at the moment of zooming smoother and without sharp jerks?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproductive example of your issue preferrably in a fiddle and describe very precisely, with examples how your current code does not fulfill your standards and what you want to achieve instead?

Comment: Of course!
https://jsfiddle.net/Leonid_Price/ko25s9v6/2/